# PHP: IF statement works on its own, but not inside WHILE loop

Tags: php, if-statement, while-loop, strtok

The problem:

Let's say I have $keyword = a sentence entered into a search box, such as "large white boxes"

What I need to do is break this into individual words, and then test each word to make sure a * doesn't appear within the first 3 letters.  (So, sen* would be ok, but se* would NOT be ok).  If a * does appear in first 3 letters of any individual word, then the "if ($keyword) ..." process needs to end.

```
if ($keyword)  {


            $token = strtok($keyword, " ");
                while ($token != false) {
                    echo $token;
                        if (stripos($token,"*") < 3 ) {
                        return;
                        }
                    $token = strtok(" ");
                    }
```

...code continues...

As you can see, I am echoing each time to see it processing.

If I get rid of the 'if' code, then it outputs 'largewhiteboxes' and continues on as expected.

If I leave the 'if' code as-is, only 'large' is output, and the routine ends - even though the condition has not been met!

If I run that 'if' statement on its own, outside of the WHILE loop, it works just fine, responding true to a * in first 3 positions, and false for everything else...

What might I be doing wrong with this???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This variation seems to work.

```
$keyword = "large white boxes";

$token = strtok($keyword, " ");

while ($token !== false) {
    echo $token;
    $pos = stripos($token, "*");
    if ($pos < 3 && $pos !== false) {
        return;
    }
    $token = strtok(" ");
}
```

Comment: A W E S O M E.  Upon initial testing, this is working ;-), I'll test some more of course... I was incorporating the !== false over  and starting to shape in this direction... but man you came right into the paint dunked it!!!  Thanks for everyone's input on this I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 2):

There is a [giant red warning in the documentation for `stripos`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stripos.php) that you should heed.

In other words, you need to check if the return value `!== false` before checking if it is `< 3`.

As an aside, why do you bother with `strtok` when `explode(',', $keyword)` is available?

Comment: Thanks... actually, stripos was already there and working... however it was checking for the first 3 characters of the entire phrase, not the individual words within the phrase.  Since it was working without issue, I really didn't look into that part of it (though, I will now).  My problem came when trying to place it inside the WHILE loop.  I actually used explode at the outset, but amid failures ended up with strtok...

Comment: strtok is actually really clever. If you have a really big string you don't want to explode it all at once and since you need to loop anyway strtok is quite efficient.

Comment: Well I wish I was as clever as the strtok command cuz then I'd have this figured out ;-) ... I'm trying some variations based on points Jon brought up, but still not having luck...

Comment: @FritsvanCampen: Sure. But you pay for that "benefit" dearly in ease of use. Do you really need it?